# Less variables are present in compiled CSS (only on multiple color operations)

Tags: css, less

I'm new to Less, and right now I'm trying to figure this out:

I added a multiple color operation on variable `@component-hover-bg`:

```
@component-hover-bg {background: lighten(desaturate(@brand-primary-four, 25%), 50%)}
```

When I compile the Less file, this specific variable pops up in my CSS:

```
@component-hover-bg { background: #b1d3ec; }
```

As you can imagine, I don't want variables in my CSS. How can I fix this? I know I could treat it as a mixin and use `()` to exclude it from CSS, but that wouldn't be very logical, because it is a variable after all.

Comment: Can't really understand what you are trying to do. What are you trying and what is the expected output?

Comment: I'm trying to calculate a variable background-colour based on a variable (@brand-primary-four). Calculation is correct (background: #b1d3ec;) but i don't want this variable in my compiled css (@component-hover-bg).

Comment: Then why don't you do it like this? `@component-hover-bg: lighten(desaturate(@brand-primary-four, 25%), 50%);` and use it like `.yourselector { background: @component-hover-bg; }`?

Comment: That works fine. The problem is, that when i use multiple color operations (lighten and desaturate in this case) on 1 specific variable, after compiling my css pops out a rule: @component-hover-bg { background: #b1d3ec; }. I don't want a variable to show up in my css file!

Comment: You aren't getting what I am saying. Your syntax is wrong. Why are you using a directive (the `@component-hover-bg` is not a variable in your case as you aren't assigning it anything - no `:`) like a `@media` query? That's why you are getting it in the output. Look at my comment and see how I have assigned the calculated value to a variable and then used it.

Comment: Ahh, now i see what you mean!! Thanks, working!

Comment: You're welcome @MartijnWijmer. I have posted my solution as an answer because that is where it belongs. Please consider marking it as accepted (click the hollow tick mark near on the left side of the answer) if it helped :)

Answer (score 0):

As explained in my comments, the syntax that you are currently using is incorrect. The below is not a variable declaration syntax. It has no `:` following the variable name and so no value is assigned. The compiler actually treats it like a CSS at-rule or directive (like the `@media` query) with the relevant rules being provided inside the `{}` block.

```
@component-hover-bg {
  background: lighten(desaturate(@brand-primary-four, 25%), 50%);
}
```

Less compiler never outputs variables into the compiled CSS file. But it always has to output all the at-rules  (like `@media`, `@namespace`, `@keyframes` etc) as-is without suppressing. Hence this gets output into the CSS file.

If you want to perform two color operations on a primary variable, set its value to another variable and then use it as the value for a property then the correct syntax is the following:

```
@component-hover-bg: lighten(desaturate(@brand-primary-four, 25%), 50%); /* calculate, assign to variable */
.yourselector {
   background: @component-hover-bg; /* use the secondary variable as the property's value */
}
```

Or, if you want to set the property + value pair to the variable then you can use the [detached rulesets](http://lesscss.org/features/#detached-rulesets-feature) feature like below:

```
@component-hover-bg: {
    background: lighten(desaturate(@brand-primary-four, 25%), 50%); /* set value to property */
};
.yourselector {
   @component-hover-bg(); /* include the ruleset */
}
```

But the second option is too restrictive. If you have a group of properties and all of them need to be set to multiple selectors then you can use this option but using a variable + value (the first option) is much better because you can then use the variable's value anywhere you wish to (like assigning value for a property, additional computations etc).